# Hibernate annotated @Query parameters not working properly

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm working with an annotated hibernate query and getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2
at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getOrdinalParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:416) ~[hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar:3.6.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter
```

Here's the code that's causing it:

```
@Query(value = "from MatchReport where match = ?1 and categoryCDList like '%?2%' or categoryCDList like '%ALL%'")
@QueryHints({ @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true") })
List<MatchReport> findByMatchAndUserType(Match match, String userType);
```

Is this being caused by not escaping the single quotes? If so, how can I escape those quotes in the annotation? I looked for documentation and came up short.

Comment: had this exact same issue--if anyone has an answer that would be awesome

Comment: what the spring-data-jpa version?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i did some tests and your query should like this:

```
@Query(value = "from MatchReport where match = ?1 
                and categoryCDList like %?2% or categoryCDList like '%ALL%'")
```

So the baseline is that you do not need to put the like condition within double brackets if the only value that will be matched against is the ordinal parameter.

The same would work with named parameter:

```
@Query(value = "from MatchReport where match = :match 
             and categoryCDList like %:usertype% or categoryCDList like '%ALL%'")
List<MatchReport> findByMatchAndUserType(
          @Param("match")Match match, @Param("usertype")String userType);
```

I was using `spring-data-jpa:1.11.0.RC1`